# LINQ : Select one item from list but it must match two values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have have following list -

[image]

How can I write a LINQ query, which gives me only those request numbers where I have both errors. In result, I just want 1 and 6 request numbers.

Right now I ma using an alternate approach like below -

```
Dim requestWithMultipleErrors As New List(Of String)
For Each requestObj As RequestErrorModel In requestErrorList
      Dim isError1 = (From item As RequestErrorModel In requestErrorList
            Where item.requestNumber = requestObj.requestNumber _
            AndAlso item.errorString.Contains("Error1")).Count > 0

      Dim isError2 = (From item As RequestErrorModel In requestErrorList
            Where item.requestNumber = requestObj.requestNumber _
            AndAlso item.errorString.Contains("Error2")).Count > 0

      If isError1 AndAlso isError2 AndAlso _
         Not requestWithMultipleErrors.Contains(requestObj.requestNumber) Then
             requestWithMultipleErrors.Add(requestObj.requestNumber)
      End If
Next
```

Comment: Group by `RequestNo` first and add a `Where gr.Count() == 2` with `Select gr.Key` after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach:

```
Dim requestErrorList As New List(Of RequestErrorModel) From
{
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 1, .errorString = "Error1" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 1, .errorString = "Error2" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 2, .errorString = "Error1" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 3, .errorString = "Error2" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 4, .errorString = "Error1" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 5, .errorString = "Error2" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 6, .errorString = "Error1" },
    New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 6, .errorString = "Error2" }
}

Dim error1s = requestErrorList.Where(Function (x) x.errorString = "Error1").Select(Function (x) x.requestNumber)
Dim error2s = requestErrorList.Where(Function (x) x.errorString = "Error2").Select(Function (x) x.requestNumber)
Dim combined = error1s.Intersect(error2s)
```

That gives:

```
1
6
```

And another approach:

```
Dim errors = requestErrorList.ToLookup(Function (x) x.errorString, Function (x) x.requestNumber)
Dim combined = errors("Error1").Intersect(errors("Error2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Group items by RequestId and then check that all selected errors exists in the group.

```
Dim errors = New List(Of String) From
{
    "Error1", "Error2"
}


var requestNumbersWithAllErrors = 
    requestErrorList.GroupBy(Function(request) request.RequestNo).
                     Where(Function(group) errors.All(Function(e) group.Contains(e))).
                     SelectMany(Function(group) group).
                     Select(Function(request) request.RequestNo)

For Each number As integer In requestNumbersWithAllErrors 
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next

' Output
' 1
' 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a collection of `RequestErrorModel` with 2 properties: `requestNumber` (as `Integer`) and `errorString`, as given there:

```
Dim requestErrorList As New List(Of RequestErrorModel)

requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 1, .errorString = "Error1" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 1, .errorString = "Error2" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 2, .errorString = "Error1" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 3, .errorString = "Error2" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 4, .errorString = "Error1" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 5, .errorString = "Error2" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 6, .errorString = "Error1" })
requestErrorList.Add(New RequestErrorModel With { .requestNumber = 6, .errorString = "Error2" })
```

You can use `Group` clause to group based on `requestNumber`, then return `requestNumber` which has 2 `errorString` items using `Count()` method:

```
' returns List(Of Integer) from requestNumber
Dim multipleErrorRequest = (From item As RequestErrorModel In requestErrorList
    Group item By item.requestNumber Into groupitem = Group
    Where groupitem.Count() = 2
    Select groupitem.FirstOrDefault().requestNumber
).ToList()
```

Then you can use `For Each` loop against `multipleErrorRequest` to get each values, or just `ConvertAll` if you want to convert directly into `requestWithMultipleErrors` string collection:

```
Dim requestWithMultipleErrors As New List(Of String)

requestWithMultipleErrors.AddRange(multipleErrorRequest.ConvertAll(Function(x) x.ToString()))
```

Working example: [DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uy8kPm)

Answer (score 0):

Given the `requestErrorList`, List of `RequestErrorModel`, create a Grouping   ([`IGrouping<TKey, TElement> Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Linq.IGrouping%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework))  using Linq `GroupBy`, considering the Groups which have more than one element.

```
Dim ErrorGroups As List(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, RequestErrorModel)) = requestErrorList.
                   GroupBy(Function(errmod) errmod.requestNumber).
                   Where(Function(grp) grp.Count() > 1).
                   ToList()
```

This return a List of elements with the same `requestNumber` value, grouped by a Key.

The Grouping can be flatten using Linq `SelectMany`, since `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`.

```
Dim ErrorList As List(Of RequestErrorModel) = ErrorGroups.
                 SelectMany(Function(grp) grp).
                 ToList()
```

This of course can be done in a single pass:

```
Dim requestWithMultipleErrors As List(Of RequestErrorModel) = requestErrorList.
                                 GroupBy(Function(errmod) errmod.requestNumber).
                                 Where(Function(grp) grp.Count() > 1).
                                 SelectMany(Function(grp) grp).
                                 ToList()
```